# child node is not getting serialized correctly

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

Having an issue trying to get the xml serialization of my model working correctly.

Here is my model:

```
 [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Invoice", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public class Invoice
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Items")]
        public virtual List<Item> Items{ get; set; }
    }
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Item")]
    public class Item
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Line")]
        public virtual int Line { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "MatNum")]
        public virtual string MatNum { get; set; }
    }
```

This results in the following XML which is WRONG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Invoice>
  <Items Line="1" MatNum="Beer">
  <Items Line="2" MatNum="Cola">
</Invoice>
```

The result SHOULD look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Invoice>
  <Items>
    <Item Line="1" MatNum="Beer">
    <Item Line="2" MatNum="Cola">
  </Items>
</Invoice>
```

What am I doing wrong?  It seems the XML serializer is ignoring the child class element.

Comment: Look up XmlArrayAttribute and XmlArrayItemAttribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok silly mistake, needed to change to an XmlArrayItem instead of Element for "Items"

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Invoice", Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
    public class Invoice
    {
        [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Item")]
        public virtual List<Item> Items { get; set; }
    }
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Item")]
    public class Item
    {
        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Line")]
        public virtual int Line { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "MatNum")]
        public virtual string MatNum { get; set; }
    }
```